# Get the 'create from' branch name from a tag push gitlab-ci

Tags: git, tags, branch, gitlab-ci

I would like to get the branch name when a tag push is done in my gitlab-ci worker.

When a push is done, the CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME var contains the branch name. But for a tag push, it's replaced by the tag itself and I didn't find a way to get the branch name.

By branch name, I refer to the 'create from' field filled, as you can see on the screenshot bellow. This field can refer to a branch that I would like to get in my gitlab-ci script.

[image: image of tag push creation]

I would like to get `development`.

Comment: A tag can be part of more than one branch. Which one do you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't.

A tag is (like a branch) a reference, a pointer to a **commit**. You commit can be in multiple branches, and Gitlab won't be able to guess which one you would like to use.

Example:

```
dc73e1c Foo
7e9e838 Bar    * 1.0, master
956750e Baz    
c938048 Qux
6dee84d Quux   * develop
```

You push the `1.0` tag, which points on `7e9e838`. This commit is part of `master` AND `develop`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I edited my question to be more explicit about my needs!

Comment: That is still not possible. In my example, you'd have created the `1.0` tag from `master` branch, which is in fact "from the commit referenced by master at this moment. But you project stil live after that, and you cannot find this branch later.

Comment: More: you can totally create a tag from a commit, and not from a branch. Is this case, what would you be looking for? It's 100% sure you won't be able to do that in Gitlab CI.